# How to convert image in to binary image using Image processing with Emgu CV

Tags: c#, tesseract, emgucv

Any suggestions to convert image into binary and remove noise from it. Submit the coding plz. I'm trying to read characters in the image using tesseract function in Emgu CV.

Comment: `Submit the coding plz` Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 5):

You can transform image into binary by converting it to grayscale and then apllying threshold after that:

```
var bwImage = colorImg.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(yourThrehold), new Gray(255));
```

if you have small blobs (salt and pepper noise) you can use median filter -function Median or erode the image (function Erode and that dilating it - funcrtion Dilate)